# Comparing text of two strings, issues with eq

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, comparison, string-comparison

## Problem

For the hockey players that are defensemen `.player--defenseman`, clicking on the `"Add to Team"` button `btn-add` multiple times replaces the text of a span after each click, **but it should not add that player's name more than once.**

### Where I'm at

- I've tried using the following if-statement `spanText !== playerName` to compare the two strings, but when I `console.log` the strings I'm getting the default text `"Pick a defenseman"` and then that player's name, despite that player being selected and his name already being in the span
- I have a feeling the problem might be the variable `spanText` or with `eq(0)`, especially with the section that deals with defensemen

### scripts.js

```
function countPlayers(){
        $(".player").click(function(){

            // Select the current player
            var player = $(this);

            // Count number of players of each position that have been clicked
            var pickedF = $(".player--forward.is-selected").length;
            var pickedD = $(".player--defenseman.is-selected").length;
            var pickedG = $(".player--goalie.is-selected").length;

            // Grab the name of the player last clicked
            playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();

            // Literally magic.
            $(".btn--add").unbind("click");

            $(".btn--add").click(function(){

                // Ensures names don't match
                var spanText = $(".player__pick").eq(0).text();

                // Changes the opacity of a picked player to 0.5
                player.addClass("is-selected");

                if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
                    if (spanText !== playerName) {
                        $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                        $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                        if (pickedF < 2) {
                            pickedF++;
                        }

                        if (pickedF === 2) {
                            $(".player--forward").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                            console.log("Locked forwards");
                        } else {
                            $(".player--forward").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Something is wonky here
                if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                    if (spanText !== playerName) {
                        $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                        $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                        console.log(spanText);
                        console.log(playerName);

                        if (pickedD < 3) {
                            pickedD++;
                        }

                        if (pickedD === 3) {
                            $(".player--defenseman").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                            console.log("Locked defensemen");
                        } else {
                            $(".player--defenseman").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                    if (spanText !== playerName) {
                        $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                        $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                        if (pickedG < 1){
                            pickedG++;
                        }

                        if (pickedG === 1) {
                            $(".player--goalie").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                            console.log("Locked goalie");
                        } else {
                            $(".player--goalie").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                        }
                    }
                }

                console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
            });

            $(".btn--remove").click(function(){
                player.removeClass("is-selected");

                if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
                    $(".player__pick--forward").eq(0).html("Pick a Forward");
                    $(".player__pick--forward").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedF > 0 && pickedF < 2) {
                        pickedF--;
                    }
                }

                if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                    $(".player__pick--defenseman").eq(0).html("Pick a Defenseman");
                    $(".player__pick--defenseman").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedD > 0 && pickedD < 3){
                        pickedD--;
                    }
                }

                if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                    $(".player__pick--goalie").eq(0).html("Pick a Goalie");
                    $(".player__pick--goalie").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedG > 0){
                        pickedG--;
                    }
                }

                console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
            });
        });
}
```

### index.html

#### Hockey players

```
<div class="player player--plante player--goalie" data-id="30">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Jacques Plante</p>
        <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="player player--brown player--defenseman" data-id="31">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Jeff Brown</p>
        <p class="player__position">Defenseman</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="player player--roberts player--defenseman" data-id="32">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Jimmy Roberts</p>
        <p class="player__position">Defenseman</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="player player--mullen player--forward" data-id="33">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Joe Mullen</p>
        <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### index.html

#### List with spans

```
        <ul>
            <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--forward is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a forward</span></li>
            <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--forward is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a forward</span></li>
            <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
            <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
            <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
            <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--goalie is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a goalie</span></li>
        </ul>
```

### index.html

#### Popup with `btn--add`

```
<div class="popup clearfix">
    <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
        <img src="" alt="" class="popup__picture animated">

        <div class="popup__text">
            <p class="popup__position">tk-position</p>
            <p class="popup__name">tk-name</p>
            <p class="popup__years">tk-years</p>
            <p class="popup__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ad dicta sunt unde, sed quae nihil inventore voluptates nulla voluptate laudantium nesciunt quo, aspernatur deleniti quod harum, nisi error doloribus.</p>
            <div class="popup__stats">
                <p>tk-stats</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="btn--add">Add to team</button>
                <button class="btn--remove">Remove from team</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it with != to compare just the string contents.

Comment: I mentioned above that for whatever reason the text of the strings are not matching despite the text of the player being in the span after the "Add to Team" button is clicked. `!=` does not solve the problem, unfortunately.